# Fifth root of an even number

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction

> Assume $x>1$ is an even integer, show that.
>   $$\sqrt[5]{x} \notin \mathbb{N}$$

I am not sure if this is actually a true theorem, I am conjecturing based on $2, 4, 6, 8, 10, .... 126$.

I am attempting to try to prove this.

Let $x = 2$, $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ hence, $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{N}$

Suppose $\sqrt{x} \notin \mathbb{N}$, the objective is to show: $\sqrt{x+2} \notin \mathbb{N}$ either.

I am not sure of the induction hypothesis since, $x+1$ will always be odd, I chose to go with $x+2$.

Comment: What happened when you tried $x=32$?

Comment: $\sqrt[m]{2^m} \in \mathbb N$ for any $m$.

Comment: Take $x = 32$ and you'll see this is false

Comment: In fact, take any positive even $y$ and then $x=y^5$ will be even. Then $\sqrt[5]{x}=y\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Supposing $x >1$ how about: $$\sqrt[5]{x(x+1)(x^4 + x^2 + 1)}$$ I conjectured this cannot be in the natural number set?

Comment: Ping @mjh (above comment)

Comment: @Lebes:  You've been around a bit, so I assume you know that your Question can be edited.  It seems you realize that the original problem is attempting to prove something false, and in the Comment above you ask a different question.  I would either Edit the Question while it remains unanswered or post that new problem as a different Question.

Answer (score 1):

As @GitGud and several other Commenters pointed out, the premise of this Question is not true.  Any fifth power of an even number is even, so $2^5 = 32$ and many other natural numbers furnish counter-examples.